# Expresso Store: When are member accounts created?

Tags: expresso-store

I have a new site coming online and looking at Store as it's worked well for me in the past. The client wants to have the following:

When clicking on Checkout, you log in, or guest checkout (with the option to create an account).

We would be using paypal website payments pro so the customer could pay by card on-site, or go off to paypal to pay via their paypal account.

So...

How does the Paypal flow work? Presumably if I login I get everything in my order history, but if I choose to create an account, and select Paypal as the checkout, what happens? Does store go off-site and then on return, create a new account, or does it create first and then go off-site? If it's the former, how does it handle the situation where an account already exists with the email address used?

Just need to make sure I'm completely clear on everything so I can advise the designers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose to create an account during checkout with Store, the customer's account is created when the order is "completed". That is, the account is created when the customer returns from PayPal (or any other off-site payment gateway).

Either way, if the `register_member` field is enabled/checked during checkout, the `order_email` field is validated to ensure it does not clash with any existing member accounts. This validation happens automatically, and only happens if `register_member` is enabled.

So, to answer your question: The situation where the customer already has an account will be handled before they are redirected to PayPal, but the account won't actually be created until payment is complete.

Comment: Sorry, another question - can you collect profile data in the checkout ahead of registration? For example date of name, date of birth etc?

Comment: No. If you want to collect a lot of details like that, it's probably easier to create a separate login/registration step before letting the customer complete their order.

Comment: Well, any mapped fields will apply to the new user (e.g. name, address, etc), but the only way to collect date of birth is if you store it in a custom order field and then map that to the member field.

Comment: OK, so provided we have created and mapped each member field to custom order fields, everything is collected? Take your point about the separate registration process but just want to be clear on the process/options before discussing in more depth with the designers.

Comment: Yes. So you can either create a separate registration step, or use the custom order fields and map them to the user fields.